# I'm making a photo album viewer but MULTISELECT is only getting one photo. How do it?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, multi-select, openfiledialog

This is windows forms. I am trying to make an album viewer where the user selects a picture using `openfiledialog` and can than view all his selections on a `picturebox` by clicking the previous and next buttons.

But when I set `multiselect` to true, only one image displays in the `picturebox` and I can't navigate through all the selected pictures. (However when I don't use multiselect and choose pictures 1 by 1, they all show in the `picturebox`.) If anyone is wondering how I display multiple images with a 1 `picturebox` its because I made previous and next buttons. (They work with one by one selections but not with `multiselect`).

```
int pageNumber = 0;
List<Photo> ImageFiles = new List<Photo>();
Photo photo;
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Multiselect = true;
    open.Filter = "Image Files(\*. jpg; \*. jpeg; \*. gif; \*. bmp)|\*. jpg; \*. jpeg; \*. gif; \*. bmp";

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

        pctBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        string textDescrip = txtDescrip.Text;
        foreach (Photo photo in open.FileNames) {

            photo = new Photo(open.FileName, textDescrip);
            ImageFiles.Add(photo);
            pctBox.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my next and previous button click handlers:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //if there is no more pages
    if (pageNumber > 0) {
        // Move to the next page
        --pageNumber;
        // Load up the PictureBox with the new image.
        pctBox.Image = new Bitmap(ImageFiles[pageNumber].fileName);
        txtDescrip.Text = ImageFiles[pageNumber].description;
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("No more images to display");
    }
}

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (pageNumber < ImageFiles.Count - 1) {
        ++pageNumber;
        pctBox.Image = new Bitmap(ImageFiles[pageNumber].fileName);
        txtDescrip.Text = ImageFiles[pageNumber].description;
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("No more images to display");
    }
}
```

Basically when I click the previous or next buttons, nothing happens and only 1 image shows on the `picturebox`.

Comment: The first step is to debug: at the end of the foreach loop does `ImageFiles` has as many items as you expect?  Is the value of `pageNumber` what you expect?  **[Using the built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**  Also, your app is leaking - you create new bitmaps in that loop and use only the last one and dispose of none of them. If you have the file name (?) use the `ImageLocation`  property

Comment: This is wrong: `foreach (Photo photo in open.FileNames)`, it should be `foreach (string photoLocation in open.FileNames) { photo = new Photo(photoLocation, textDescrip); }`. After the loop, set the `pctBox.Image` to the first Image in the list.

Comment: What is `Photo` here - a redefinition of `string`? Because at least one mistake you have is to reference `open.FileName` in your `foreach` inside `btnAdd_Click` - it should be `photo` since you're enumerating a list of files. This confusion stems from the fact that `OpenDialog` doubles both as a single- and multi-select dialog.